# Obstacles of Message Transmission and Reception via Channels

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I am creating a loop that infinitely loops through my database for scheduled message and send it.

The code executes but here comes the case that the `createSmsMessage` function is not completely executed before proceeding

I am trying to create a loop in my application which loops infinitely through the database and gets the scheduled messages and send them.
But when the function executes the `createsmsMessage` function does not execute

This is my loop function which loops through my database for the scheduled messages and send them.

```
func SchedularLoop() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    stop := make(chan struct{})
    schedularChan := make(chan \[\]models.MessageScheduler)
    errorChan := make(chan error)
    createMessageChan := make(chan \*models.Message)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var createMessageWG sync.WaitGroup

    db := databaseapi.NewApiConfig{}

    messageService := messages.NewMessage(db.Postgres_DB_Api(), ctx)

    go func() {
        defer close(schedularChan)
        defer close(errorChan)

        for {
            data, err := GetAllSchedules(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                errorChan \<- fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err)
            }

            schedularChan \<- data

            time.Sleep(5 \* time.Second)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for msgs := range schedularChan {
            currentTime := time.Now()
            TodayDate := utilities.FormatDate(currentTime)
            fmt.Println("Today's Date", TodayDate)

            for \_, data := range msgs {
                schDate := utilities.FormatDate(data.ScheduledDate)

                if schDate == TodayDate {
                    messageData, err := messageService.GetMessage(data.MessageID, ctx)
                    if err != nil {
                        errorChan \<- err
                    }
                    if !messageData.IsSms {
                        fmt.Println("I'm not a voice message")
                    }

                    smsMessage := &models.Message{
                        UserID:        data.UserID,
                        GroupID:       messageData.GroupID,
                        ID:            uuid.New(),
                        MessageTitle:  messageData.MessageTitle,
                        IsScheduled:   false,
                        Recipients:    messageData.Recipients,
                        Content:       messageData.Content,
                        Sender:        messageData.Sender,
                        ScheduledDate: time.Now().String(),
                        CreatedAt:     messageData.CreatedAt,
                        UpdatedAt:     time.Now(),
                    }

                    createMessageWG.Add(1)
                    go func() {
                        defer createMessageWG.Done()
                        fmt.Println("Createmessage routine")
                        CrmsgData, err := messageService.CreateSmsMessage(smsMessage, ctx)
                        fmt.Println("Sent Data", CrmsgData)
                        if err != nil {
                            fmt.Println("Error creating SMS message:", err.Error())
                            errorChan \<- err
                        } else {
                            createMessageChan \<- CrmsgData
                            fmt.Println("Testing Message Created", createMessageChan)
                        }

                    }()
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for msg := range createMessageChan {
            fmt.Println(msg)
            fmt.Println("Create Message working oooo")
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Add(1)
    wg.Wait()

    defer close(stop)
}
```

Below is my `CreateSmsMessage` function:

```
func (msgService \*MessagesServiceImplementation) CreateSmsMessage(msg \*models.Message, ctx context.Context) (\*models.Message, error) {

    fmt.Println(msg.ScheduledDate)
    userService := usersimpl.NewUserService(msgService.pg, ctx)
    \_, err := userService.GetUserById(msg.UserID, ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err)
    }

    errorChannel := make(chan error)
    dbChanel := make(chan database_utils.Message)
    msgChannel := make(chan \*mnotify.SMSData)

    if msg.GroupID.UUID != uuid.Nil {
        // Search/Check for the existence of groupID
        groupService := group.NewGroupService(msgService.pg, ctx)
        // Check for group existence
        groupId := msg.GroupID.UUID
        \_, err := groupService.GetGroupById(groupId, ctx)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("group does not exist Reason: %v", err)
        }

        // If the group exist, lets get all the subscribers that belong to the user phoneNumbers
        var sub models.Subscribers
        sub.UserID = msg.UserID
        sub.GroupID = msg.GroupID
        subscriberService := subscribers.NewUserService(msgService.pg, ctx)
        phoneNumbers, err := subscriberService.GetAllUserSubscribersPhoneByGroupID(&sub, ctx)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err)
        }

        // Lets Pass the users in the group phone numbers
        msg.Recipients = phoneNumbers

        params := &database_utils.CreateSMSMessageParams{
            ID:            uuid.New(),
            MessageTitle:  msg.MessageTitle,
            IsSms:         true,
            Sender:        msg.Sender,
            GroupID:       msg.GroupID,
            Recipients:    msg.Recipients,
            Content:       msg.Content,
            UserID:        msg.UserID,
            MsgLanguage:   msg.Title,
            CreatedAt:     msg.CreatedAt,
            ScheduledDate: msg.ScheduledDate,
            IsScheduled:   msg.IsScheduled,
        }

        go func() {
            data, err := msgService.pg.Postgres_DB_Api().DB.CreateSMSMessage(ctx, \*params)
            if err != nil {
                errorChannel \<- fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err)
                return
            }

            dbChanel \<- data
        }()

        // Lets get the sender by ID
        var sender models.SmsSender
        sender.UserID = msg.UserID
        sender.ID = msg.Sender.UUID

        senderService := smssendergo.NewSmsSenderService(msgService.pg, ctx)
        senderData, err := senderService.GetSmsSenderAndUserID(&sender, ctx)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err)
        }

        var mnotifyMsg models.QuickBulkSms
        mnotifyMsg.Is_Schedule = false
        mnotifyMsg.Message = msg.Content
        mnotifyMsg.Recipient = msg.Recipients
        mnotifyMsg.Sender = senderData.Name

        // Lets send the message
        go func() {
            mnotifyService := mnotifycampaign.NewCampaign(msgService.pg, ctx)
            data, sendErr := mnotifyService.CreateQuickBulkSMS(&mnotifyMsg)
            if sendErr != nil {
                errorChannel \<- fmt.Errorf("error: %v", sendErr)
            }

            msgChannel \<- data
        }()

        select {
        case data := \<-dbChanel:
            return models.DbMsgtoDbMsg(data), nil
        case errorChnx := \<-errorChannel:
            return nil, errorChnx
        case \<-time.After(time.Second \* 5):
            return nil, errors.New("timeout error")
        }

    }

    if msg.GroupID.UUID == uuid.Nil {

        params := &database_utils.CreateSMSMessageParams{
            ID:           uuid.New(),
            MessageTitle: msg.MessageTitle,
            IsSms:        true,
            Sender:       msg.Sender,
            GroupID:      msg.GroupID,
            Recipients:   msg.Recipients,
            Content:      msg.Content,
            UserID:       msg.UserID,
            MsgLanguage:  msg.Title,
            CreatedAt:    msg.CreatedAt,
            UpdatedAt:    msg.UpdatedAt,
            IsScheduled:  msg.IsScheduled,
        }

        go func() {
            data, err := msgService.pg.Postgres_DB_Api().DB.CreateSMSMessage(ctx, \*params)
            if err != nil {
                errorChannel \<- fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err.Error())
                return
            }

            dbChanel \<- data
        }()

        // // Lets get the sender by ID
        var sender models.SmsSender
        sender.UserID = msg.UserID
        sender.ID = msg.Sender.UUID

        senderService := smssendergo.NewSmsSenderService(msgService.pg, ctx)
        senderData, err := senderService.GetSmsSenderAndUserID(&sender, ctx)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err.Error())
        }

        var mnotifyMsg models.QuickBulkSms
        mnotifyMsg.Is_Schedule = false
        mnotifyMsg.Message = msg.Content
        mnotifyMsg.Recipient = msg.Recipients
        mnotifyMsg.Sender = senderData.Name

        // // Lets send the message
        go func() {
            mnotifyService := mnotifycampaign.NewCampaign(msgService.pg, ctx)
            response, sendErr := mnotifyService.CreateQuickBulkSMS(&mnotifyMsg)
            if sendErr != nil {
                errorChannel \<- fmt.Errorf("error: %v", sendErr.Error())
            }

            msgChannel \<- response
        }()

        select {
        case data := \<-dbChanel:
            return models.DbMsgtoDbMsg(data), nil
        case errorChnx := \<-errorChannel:
            return nil, errorChnx
        case \<-time.After(time.Second \* 5):
            return nil, errors.New("timeout error")
        }
    }

    return nil, errors.New("invalid request")

}
```

Comment: Please try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or, at a minimum, let us know what happens when you run this (i.e. what is output vs what you expect). Please also further explain what you mean by "is not completely executed before proceeding"; `CreateSmsMessage` is run in a goroutine so runs independently, I note that you have `createMessageWG` but the code in your question does not `Wait` on that.